# Angular: nested div clicked

Tags: angular

I have a nested div. Both has a (click) event.

```
<div id="outer" (click)="foo (1)">
  <div id="inner" (click)="foo (2)">
  </div>
</div>
```

If I click outer then I get foo(1).
If I click inner I get foo(2) and then foo(1).

1. How can I make it the angular way to only get foo(2) if I click inner?
2. How can I make inner to ignore any click in inner?

   *click=""* or *click="false"* does not work.

Comment: Pass `$event` into `foo`, and do `event.stopPropagation()` inside foo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
<div id="outer" (click)="foo (1)">
  <div id="inner" (click)="(e) => {foo (2); e.stopPropagation()}">
  </div>
</div>
```